# Synology DSM - Can't log as root (but works with admin)

Tags: login, root

After some automatic updates (or being hacked?) I have many things broken and a huge problem to resolve them since **I can't login as root anymore**.

- ssh admin: login success
- su root: permission denied (probably not the same password)

What I have tried:

- read log: but permission denied
- use 'synopass' and empty password: failed
- use synouser: permission denied
- change password of admin hoping it will update the root password: failed.
- check the root user in /etc/passwd: he is ok (with ash)
- restart all the server: failed

I have no idea what is going on. Any advice?

Comment: sudo su works and solve the problem but the situation is not clear.

Comment: In /etc/shadow we can see "root:*:" so I suppose we can't login in root directly anymore and we have to use sudo. DSM release notes just speak about ssh but... ok ^^

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your Synology probably upgraded to DSM6, in which security has been hardened...
In DSM6 you can no longer use root for SSH, but you can use any other member account of the administrators group. 
Mind that you now need to sudo when logged in using SSH.

See the DSM6 release notes!

Comment: I knew that we could not ssh as root (I checked the ssh conf). What I don't understand is why we can't "su root" ? I mean, we can, but the root password is not the same as admin anymore and I have no idea what it is.

Comment: This answer has the _reason_ and will be complete if merged with @JulienGrimal answer that has the _solution_. Also, the _"See release notes"_ statement will be great if it's linked.

Comment: if you set ssh key for root user, you can login in ssh

Answer (score 35):

If your synology is in DSM6 and you're logged with a user part of administrator group, you can do :

**sudo -i**

enter your root/admin password

or even **sudo su -** (it works to)

now you're root tadaaa

Comment: Here's the synology documentation : https://www.synology.com/en-global/knowledgebase/DSM/tutorial/General/What_is_the_username_and_default_password_for_accessing_my_Synology_Product_via_Telnet_SSH

Comment: +1 But for `sudo -i` has to enter the ***current logged user password*** _(in admin group of course)_. Use `admin` pass only if you are logged in as `admin`. _>[DSM 6 Doc.](https://www.synology.com/en-global/knowledgebase/DSM/tutorial/General/How_to_login_to_DSM_with_root_permission_via_SSH_Telnet)_

Comment: `sudo su -` worked for me, DSM 7.1.1

Answer (score 10):

In DSM Version 6 you can still login as root when using RSA keys. Therefore just copy your public key as admin to your Synolgy:

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh admin@192.168.1.10 'umask 077; cat >>/tmp/authorized_keys'
```

After that login to your Synology as admin and become root:

```
$ ssh admin@192.168.1.10
admin@192.168.1.10's password:
admin@My-Synology:/$ sudo -i
Password:
```

No create the .ssh directory for root, move your key and change the owner of that file:

```
root@My-Synology:~# mkdir -m0700 /root/.ssh
root@My-Synology:~# mv /tmp/authorized_keys /root/.ssh/
root@My-Synology:~# chown root:root /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

After that you can login to your Synology as root without having to enter the password.

Comment: Does this expose any security concern?

Comment: This does not expose security problems. Since you are using a public and private key combination. It only causes security issues is they manage to get the private key

Comment: perfect, this is what i was looking for works for ssh.
doesn't work for SFTP - is there away to make that work?

Comment: Works on DSM 7 as of Feb 19 2023

Comment: @The-VinhVO if you admin account is broken, it is a security problem, so use a complexity password if your server is open in public internet.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just SSH using rsa keys, then you can SSH as root, even after installing DSM6, without making any additional changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still with DSM Version 5, you might have logged in as admin instead of root. This makes a difference, even though root and admin share the same password.

To solve, do

```
ssh root@synology.local
```

with using the admin password.

This will log you in as root, with root access.