# Synology cannot sudo to root

Tags: ssh, sudo, synology

My current DSM is 6.1.4-15217 Update 5.
There is something I do not understand :

I can ssh via an admin account, root account (yes, I shouldn't be according to docs) and my user account (john) which is in administrators group.

For security reasons, I would like to only allow connection through ssh with user account (john) and then do sudo root/admin if required.

For the moment, although I can log using root/admin, Once logged with John, I cannot sudo to root or admin (I triple checked the password used, account is not locked since I can always connect through ssh).

When I say connect, that means using putty from a windows box.

What is amiss in my configuration ?

Thanks for your input

Comment: Please describe your steps and errors you get. Ensure that you use John's password when do sudo.

Comment: As requested : 
Launch putty, connect as john.
Session is opened on Synology, then su <enter> 
I type root password.
I get Permission denied.

su admin
I type root password.
I get Permission denied.

Comment: Try `sudo -i` with john password instead of su. Looks very similar to your question: https://superuser.com/questions/1057853/synology-dsm-cant-log-as-root-but-works-with-admin

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I just moved and had no internet since.  It indeed worked with John's password. By the way, the previous question was not mine, although it looked a lot alike. Plz provide as an answer so that I can Give you the "answer valid tag" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try sudo -i with john password instead of su. Looks very similar to your question: [Synology DSM - Can't log as root (but works with admin)](https://superuser.com/questions/1057853/synology-dsm-cant-log-as-root-but-works-with-admin)